# how to target specific pixel width using media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hello I have a question regarding media queries for a specific width and no other widths.

I want to target a screen width of 768px and no other width. Right now to target it I am using

```
@media (max-width:769px) and (min-width:768px) {
    /* my css */
}​
```

This is working fine but it is preventing my other media queries below it to not work. for example when i go:

```
@media (max-width:769px) and (min-width:768px) {
    /* my css */
}​

@media (max-width:600px) {
   /* this css will not work */
}​
```

I have a strong feeling it is something to do with the min-width so is there any way to target a width of 768px only without using min-width?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try the lower screen size first and the higher one second.

Comment: that works but is that the only solution to this issue? i dont want to have the min width media query to always be at the very bottom of the css because any css below it will not work. it messeds up with my organization but if there is no other way i will have to go that route. thanks for your response.

Comment: Maybe try @media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:769px) but in the same spot you had before. Basically using min first and max second.

Answer (score 6):

In Order to specific pixel I have used below code -

```
@media (min-width:767px) and (max-width:768px) {

  /* CSS To Target 767 px width of screen */

}
```

When you use above media query change will be for 767 and 768px so you need to do reciprocal code in 768px as well.

For Example - If you are hiding a image at 767px but want to show in 768px to 991px media query then you can use -

```
@media (min-width:767px) and (max-width:768px) {

   /* CSS To Target 767 px width of screen */

  /* Hide Image at 767 px */
  .hide-logo-image{ 
      dispaly: none;
   }
}
```

Then You also need to do reciprocal code in 768px to 991px media query as below -

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {

  /* CSS To Target screen above 768px and below 991px width of screen */

  /* Show Image above 768 px */
  .hide-logo-image{ 
      dispaly: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:769px) {
    /* my css */
}

@media (max-width:992px)
  {
    /* my css */
    }
```